# JAVA Classloader.loadClass(...), get classes specified by REGEX

Tags: java, regex, classloader

I think lot of people using reflections and for example:

```
...INSTANCE = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(CLASS_NAME).newInstance();
```

Load class method takes only concrete class name.

Is there any implementation which would do:

```
List<Class> loadClasses(String REGEX)
```

By regex we could get more classes matches...

hm?

Comment: Look into the Reflections library. I don't think you can use regex, but there is probably something you can do with wildcards, `?` or `*`.

Comment: You can write Your own class loader which could be capable of loading list of classes matched by regex

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect the classpath on your own, reading the `java.class.path` system property, as FQDN of classes can be usually built from ther relative `.class` path.

Anyway, my guess is that you're looking for a mechanism just like the [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) facility.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want something that will automatically load all classes on the system classpath whose fully-qualified binary names match a regex like `^com\.` or `^org\.`?  I'm sure you have something less inclusive in mind, but you can see the potential for abuse.  And it seems like there would be extremely few worthwhile uses for such a facility.